# D-Link DI-624 H/W ver. D: Flashing OpenWrt

Tags: embedded, openwrt, dd-wrt

I have a D-Link DI-624 rev. D2 Router. It is based around an Atheros AR2316A-001 chipset, and has 8MB RAM.

I opened the device to check for actual parts use in it, and I can confirm, it is indeed the AR2316A-001 chipset with PSC A2V64S40CTP (8MB RAM). I couldn't locate the flash chip, the original firmware is 1MB in size, I don't know if anything larger can be loaded onto the device.

I was wondering, If I could load [OpenWrt](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/start) on it, so I compiled OpenWrt with the AR231x chipset as Target. Now, the compile process yielded those squashfs images:

```
openwrt-atheros-np25g-squashfs.bin
openwrt-atheros-ubnt2-pico2-squashfs.bin
openwrt-atheros-ubnt2-squashfs.bin
openwrt-atheros-ubnt5-squashfs.bin
openwrt-atheros-wpe53g-squashfs.bin
```

All those files are around 2.4MB to 2.5MB in size, which is far more, than the firmware available from D-Link (`di624revD_firmware_404.bin` is around 1MB). I was wondering which file I should try to upload if any.

On the [DD-WRT page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices) for supported devices this router is listed, revision C, which uses the same chipset.

The DI-624 has an interesting emergency feature comparable to other D-Link products, like the DIR-600: When holding down the reset button while connecting power to the device, the router goes into an emergency restore mode. Then, when going to 192.168.0.1 with a browser, you can upload another firmware, no matter how badly bricked the router is.

In case anyone succeeded with flashing an alternative OS onto a DI-624, I'd very much like to know how. There was some guy at the OpenWrt forums that claimed he could boot Linux on the DI-624, but he didn't really explain how he did it.

*I wasn't sure whether this question belongs here or [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you determine, what type and size of Flash ROM is used in the device, you should not risk flashing it with anything other than dedicated firmware. Atheros chipsets are very common across a wide range of wireless devices and the sole fact of using a particular chip does not guarantee that the entire device will work correctly with your firmware. The chipset is like a coputer CPU + some peripherals, but *not necessarily* all. And the system storage *must* be supported.

**Edit**: If you'd read carefully, you'd see that [the page you linked to](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices) presents a list of **incompatible** devices. Since DI-624 is listed there, it is definitely **not supported** by dd-wrt. This makes it almost certain, that your custom OpenWrt image would **not work** either.

Comment: OK, this sucks. Any suggestions how I could identify the flash ROM chip, or another minimalistic firmware, that would fit in 1MB?

Comment: If neither dd-wrt nor OpenWrt declare to support it, chances are very low. If standard web search does not yield any obvious dedicated projects, there probably isn't any alternative.

Comment: Yeah, you could always *try* to strip down the ROM image to 1MB... But look realistically at this: if that were achievable for experienced embedded developers, such as dd-wrt or OpenWrt team, they would have already done it.

Comment: Waaait a second! The list lists devices that are *not* compatible with DD-WRT, right? it Lists DI-624 vC3. I have version D1 (that's what's  written on the PCB) / D2 (that's what's written on the label on the back of the device)! I may be quite lucky here.

Comment: **Noope.** Just... read carefully again, what the page says at the top: *"A router can not be supported by dd-wrt if: (...) it has <2MB flash"* Sorry, this *really* is the end of the road, if there is only 1MB of Flash.

Comment: I know, I've read it another time, more carefully. The Problem is, I don't know how big the flash ROM is. As I said before, I couldn't identify the ROM chip, and I couldn't find any online resource, that states the ROM size. There is some guy that actually has Linux running on his DI-624: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=59259#p59259

Comment: Looking at [that picture](http://img512.imageshack.us/img512/4024/frontte8.th.jpg) from the forum post you've linked to, I can bet that it is the chip with "ESMT" written on it. Locate similar chip in your device, read the symbol and search it at datasheetcatalog.com or alldatasheet.com or datasheetarchive.com.

Comment: @rozcoetrzewiacz: the ESMT chip in that picture, which is a PSC chip on mine, is the 64Mbit RAM (8MB RAM). I have located the Flash ROM on my device, it's a Spansion FL016A1f 16MBit (2MB) flash ROM.

Comment: So it seems you might be lucky after all. Just stick with what the author of [that post](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=59259#p59259) writes and contact him/her personally, since it looks like a far-from-typical route you'll need to take. Mind that the procedure will probably *remove the ability to easily reflash the device*, as you've described (it looks like there's a two-stage system, which you'd have to replace *entirely*).

Answer (score 0):

there are many different versions of DL-624, some of them are 1mb flash but, some are 2,4,8 or 16mb but, it is still not compatiable, i think they don't have time to really look at all of them... too bad.